# How to load child items while click parent item in ExpandableListView

Tags: java, android

I am new for android,
I have an ExpandableListView in my app. I want to load child items only while click parent Item. I tried alot but its not working . Please anyone help.

My code here:

```
ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
ExpandableListView expListView;
List<String> listDataHeader;
HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.faq, container, false);
    // get the listview
    expListView = (ExpandableListView) view.findViewById(R.id.faqList);
    prepareListData();
    listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(getActivity(),listDataHeader,listDataChild);
    // setting list adapter
    expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    // Listview Group expanded listener
    expListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(this);
    return view;
}

private void prepareData(String s) {
    Log.d("Working:","yes");

    listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
   // Adding child data
    List<String> top250 = new ArrayList<String>();
    if(s.equals("Top 250")){
        top250 = new ArrayList<String>();
        top250.add("The Shawshank Redemption Godfather");
    }else if(s.equals("Now Showing")){
        top250 = new ArrayList<String>();
        top250.add("The Conjuring welcome to your world of India");
    }else if(s.equals("Coming Soon..")){
        top250 = new ArrayList<String>();
        top250.add("2 Guns of Indias");
    }else {
        top250 = new ArrayList<String>();
        top250.add("Nothing");
    }
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), top250); // Header, Child data
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), top250);
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), top250);
}

private void prepareListData() {
    listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
    listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    // Adding child data
    listDataHeader.add("Top 250");
    listDataHeader.add("Now Showing");
    listDataHeader.add("Coming Soon..");

    // Adding child data
    List<String> top250 = new ArrayList<String>();
    top250.add("The Shawshank Redemption");
    top250.add("The Godfather");
    top250.add("The Godfather: Part II");
    top250.add("Pulp Fiction");
    top250.add("The Good, the Bad and the Ugly");
    top250.add("The Dark Knight");
    top250.add("12 Angry Men");

    List<String> nowShowing = new ArrayList<String>();
    nowShowing.add("The Conjuring");
    nowShowing.add("Despicable Me 2");
    nowShowing.add("Turbo");
    nowShowing.add("Grown Ups 2");
    nowShowing.add("Red 2");
    nowShowing.add("The Wolverine");

    List<String> comingSoon = new ArrayList<String>();
    comingSoon.add("2 Guns");
    comingSoon.add("The Smurfs 2");
    comingSoon.add("The Spectacular Now");
    comingSoon.add("The Canyons");
    comingSoon.add("Europa Report");

    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), top250); // Header, Child data
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), nowShowing);
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), comingSoon);
}

@Override
public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {

    prepareData(listDataHeader.get(groupPosition));
    listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(getActivity(),listDataHeader,listDataChild);
    listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    // setting list adapter
    expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Expanded",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: @hikoo check [this](http://www.mobiledevguide.com/2012/09/how-to-work-with-android.html)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look this URL

[URL](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/)

This may be help full for you

Comment: Im working like that only.. But its loaded before click parent items.. But i want to load item after click parent items

Comment: At the time of expandable listview object creation                            listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(getActivity(),listDataHeader,listDataChild);
    // setting list adapter
    expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);  your given listDataChild (child list data) so  loading.